# Error Import pyodbc

Tags: python, plone, zope, pyodbc

I need to install `ZPyODBCDA` product. You need to install `pyodbc` module in my python.

I'm trying to install `pyodbc` on Python 2.4.6, but when I do `import pyodbc` I got the following error:

```
dynamic module does not define init function (initpyodbc)
```

Help, please!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
try:
    import pyodbc
except ImportError:
    import odbc as pyodbc
```

In past I was the same problem and solved with this tip!